# SQL Query help (possibly use JOIN?)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table A [PATIENT] has columns [PATID], [FIRSTVISITDATE]

Table B [APPT] has columns [APPTID], [PATID], [CREATEDATE]

Table C [NOTE] has columns [NOTEID], [NOTETEXT]

Table D [PROCS] has column [PROCID], [PATID]

Table E [CHARGE] has columns [CHARGEID], [AMOUNT]

I need to sum CHARGE(AMOUNT) by PATID for all PATIENTS where the NOTE.NOTETEXT contains 'text' and one of the APPT  for a PATIENT containing the 'text' has an APPT.CREATEDATE = to the PATIENT.FIRSTVISITDATE

Simply put I need to SUM the charges for PATIENTS if they have an appointment with 'text' in their notes and the appointment with that 'text' was their first visit to the office

Other key points:

CHARGE.CHARGEID = PROC.PROCID

NOTE.NOTEID = APPT.APPTID

With my limited knowledge of SQL I was able to sum for all patients regardless if the 'text' was included in their first appointments notes and for that I used:

```
select (SUM(AMOUNT)) as 'Cash Payments' from CHARGE where CHARGEID in
  (select PROCID from PROC where PATID in
     (select PATID from APPT where APPTID in
        (select NOTEID from NOTE where NOTETEXT like '%text%')))
```

Comment: Sorry, but what you need *desperately* is to find a SQL tutorial and work your way through it. The query you've written may produce the results you want, but if you get more than a few rows of data it's performance is going to be slower than a turtle climbing Mount Everest.

Comment: i realize I know little about SQL which is why I posted it here but if this site is not for answers then I am sorry. I thought thats what this was used for

Comment: It's for answers, but simply answering this question isn't going to benefit you. You need more instruction than someone just writing a query for you. This isn't a tutorial site where we teach basics and provide long term instruction.

Comment: I see the question is tagged mysql and sql-server. Those are two VERY different database engines. You need to edit this question to be tagged for the correct database type and only the correct database type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause to group the `AMOUNT` by patient. You can filter your patients to just the ones with the `text` in the notes and `FIRSTVISITDATE` = `CREATEDATE` using an inner query that joins the tables on those conditions.

I have not tested the following query, but it should do what you're asking.

```
SELECT pa.PATIENT, SUM(c.AMOUNT) AS 'Cash Payments'
FROM PATIENT pa
INNER JOIN PROCS pr
ON pa.PATID = pr.PATID
INNER JOIN CHARGE c
ON pr.PROCID = c.CHARGEID
WHERE pa.PATIENT IN (
        SELECT pa.PATIENT
        FROM PATIENT pa
        INNER JOIN APPT a
        ON pa.PATID = a.PATID
        AND pa.FIRSTVISITDATE = a.CREATEDATE
        INNER JOIN NOTE n
        ON a.APPTID = n.NOTEID
        WHERE n.NOTETEXT LIKE '%text%'
)
GROUP BY pa.PATIENT;
```